# How can I git push to a specific folder?

Tags: github, travis-ci, github-pages

I'm using Travis CI to build my Jekyll site and push to Github. A lot of documentation around is for keeping the Jekyll code in the `master` branch, and building the site and pushing `_site` to the `gh-pages` branch. I want to avoid doing that and use the `username.github.io` repo on Github.

This is currently my build script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# skip if build is triggered by pull request
if [ $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == "true" ]; then
  echo "this is PR, exiting"
  exit 0
fi

# enable error reporting to the console
set -e

# cleanup "_site"
rm -rf _site
mkdir _site

# build with Jekyll into "_site"
bundle exec jekyll build

# push
cd _site
git config user.email "john.doe@gmail.com"
git config user.name "John Doe"
git add --all
git commit -a -m "Travis #$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"
git push origin master
```

Of course, `git push origin master` as of now replaces the entire branch itself with the generated site. How do I generate the site and keep it within `_site`?

Comment: Found a workaround. Using a `build` branch to build the site and push the built site to the `master` branch for Github Pages to use.  

1. Added `git clone https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/usrname/username.github.io.git --branch master _site` before `bundle exec jekyll build` in the script.  
2. Updated .travis.yml to build only from the `build` branch.  
3. Updated settings on Travis CI dashboard to build only if .travis.yml is present, else it'll build when `_site`'s content are pushed to `master`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are running this script inside some folder. lets call that `my_project`.

Inside `my_folder`, when you run this script, it creates a `_site` folder.
Next you are doing `cd _site`. Dont do this.

Instead, remain at `my_project` folder and do the git config steps and others at this level.

So this will push all the stuff inside this `my_project` folder and the site will be inside the `_site` folder.

Comment: Thanks! This didn't quite work. Found a workaround instead, which I've posted as a comment above to the question.

Answer (score 0):

**TL,DR:**

Change these lines:
`git add --all`
`git commit -a -m "Travis #$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"`

To:
`git add ./ #I assume you've cd'd into the directory you want to commit.`
`git commit -m "Travis #$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"`

---

**Explanation**:

This question smells like a problem that someone coming from svn would have.(Skip the next paragraph if you aren't coming from svn)

There is a big difference in the way svn and git handle commits.
When you use svn, the commit always works relative to the current directory. So, the line `cd _site` changes what is known as the present working directory to `_site`. And there on out, svn only is concerned about the current directory and its children.

On the other hand, git commands will climb the directory path till they reach the root. So, when you are in `_site` and give a command with a `--all`or `-a` *it will commit all the changes in the whole branch*.
So, you replace --all with `./` in the add command which is just linux shorthand for the present directory. And remove the `-a` in the commit command. So the "changes added" are only from the present directory ie `_site`. This stages the changes for commit. You remove the `-a` from the commit command so that it only commits the staged changes.

As an aside, `git add --all` followed by `git commit -a` is redundant. The `-a` in commit ignores what is added to the stage and just commits all changes.

Comment: PS: directory == folder